# search for zip files of Google Plugin for Eclipse3.7(indigo)

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I want to find the zip files of the Google Plugin for Eclipse3.7(indigo). At the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#installfromzip) I didn't find any zip file for Eclipse 3.7. And the zip file for Eclipse3.6(Helios) doesn't support 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be this one, is for windows right?

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32.zip

or this other:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-win32.zip

Also in the same link that you provide in the

"Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7(Indigo) Installation Instructions"
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7#selectcomponents

**They put the link in order to download the latest update site archive for Eclipse 3.7.**

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/core/3.7/zips/gpe-e37-latest-updatesite.zip

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. Maybe I have not expressed clearly. I want to look for the Google plugin which can be installed in Eclipse 3.7. I want to use the Google plugin to develop web applications.

Comment: I have downloaded the zip file and it's OK. Thank you very much!